# Remove voted sign if an error occurs during voting

Tags: feature-request, bug, voting

I noticed that whenever I try to upvote or downvote a post and an error occurs during voting E.g I lost internet connection, The already voted sign is still shown and the vote count still increases by one.

[image]

Now when I regain my internet connection, I'll have to refresh the page inorder to vote on the post again. If I try clicking on the already voted sign (without refreshing), Nothing happens.

I'll appreciate it if I didn't have to refresh the page. My proposal is that the already voted sign should be removed and the vote count should decrease if an error occurs during voting. Something like

[image]

Now when I regain my internet connection, I can just click the upvote button again and upvote (without refreshing)

Comment: There are _a ton_ of bugs like this (try opening the question in two tabs for instance and voting - it'll show the vote on the second tab but won't indicate it's yours). My guess is that the system prefers speed and simplicity over optimizing edge cases. I mean, after all - you knew exactly what was happening and it _is_ an edge case. Still - this is a nice, simple suggestion. I'd label it as bug instead of feature-request if I were you.

Comment: I would say its more of a bug since it is not accurately showing the status of your vote in this case. It isn't a feature to show you as having voted on a question when you have not rather it is a bug.

Comment: The same thing is even more annoyingwhen on the mobile website when I'm on a slow connection. I never know if my vote was counted. I wait a few seconds and then refresh the whole page to see.